# Does angular2 have ngCloak

Tags: angular

AngularJS 1.x has ngCloak directive, which is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form.

Does Angular 2 have any such directive or functionality to prevent such raw(uncompiled) form display.

Comment: [This](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html) should be helpful..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Angular2 desn' have **ngCloak**,

instead you can use `?.` operator (use it with object).

```
{{user?.name}}
```

AND/OR

you can use ***ngIf** (as of now)

```
<div *ngIf="name"> {{name}}</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two types of compilations in Angular2 ,Just-in-Time(JiT) and
Ahead-of-Time(AoT). Just-in-Time is the default compilation.

**JiT compilation** incurs a runtime performance penalty.Views take longer to render because of the in-browser compilation step. The application is bigger because it includes the Angular compiler and a lot of library code that the application won't actually need. Bigger apps take longer to transmit and are slower to load.

**With AoT**, the browser downloads a pre-compiled version of the application. The browser loads executable code so it can render the application immediately, without waiting to compile the app first.

If we go with Ahead-of-Time compilation instead of Just-in-Time compilation,
we can prevent such raw(uncompiled) form of display.

[This](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) link provides more information

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent rendering of html by using *ngIf until the corresponding object is loaded:

```
<div *ngIf="dataList">
<>....</>
</div>
```